# Converting objective-c method to swift [updateSearchResultsForSearchController]

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate

I'm trying to convert the following Objective-C method to Swift, but I've came across a few issues.

I'm having trouble using the Predicate as it's described below to the Swift syntax.

Can someone give me a hint?

```
- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {

// filter the search results
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains [cd] %@", self.controller.searchBar.text];
self.results = [self.data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

// NSLog(@"Search Results are: %@", [self.results description]);
```

}

Regards, IC

Comment: Sorry... It's a String Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF contains[cd] %@", self.controller.searchBar.text!)
results = data.filter({ item in
    predicate.evaluateWithObject(item)
})
```

Or for a more concise solution:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF contains[cd] %@", self.controller.searchBar.text!)
results = data.filter { predicate.evaluateWithObject($0) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF contains [cd] %@", argumentArray: [self.controller.searchBar.text])
    self.results = (self.data as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)
}
```

Comment: The array property doesn't have the filteredArrayUsingPredicate method

Comment: You can cast it to an `NSArray`. See my edited answer

Comment: Just seen :) I'll try that as you suggested